# Netbeans Basic Http Auth Jax-WS

Tags: web-services, netbeans, jax-ws, webservice-client, http-authentication

how can I access a webservice through a basic http authentification? I am using the netbeans built in webservice client features. But when I try to access the webservice, I get an exception with a 401 auth failed error message.

How can I pass the right username and password?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You could use BindingProvider or WSBindingProvider class to access a Web Service through a basic http authentification.
The code is as follows.

```
XxxService service = new XxxService();
Xxx port = service.getXxxPort();

Map<String, Object> reqContext = ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext();
reqContext.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "username");
reqContext.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "password");
```

Comment: This will work if the WSDL is not protected himself by Basic Http Authentication

Comment: why it doesn't work for me? I have exactly that `AImpl aImplPort = new AImplService().getAImplPort();
        BindingProvider prov = (BindingProvider) aImplPort;

        prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "fred");
        prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "fred");

        String b = aImplPort.b();
        System.out.println(b);` it isn't sending expected Authorization http header

Answer (score 3):

You can also provide your own Authenticator. That way it will work even if the WDSL itself is protected by basic HTTP authentication.

```
@WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "https://laka/sito?wsdl")
static XxxService service;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("user", "password".toCharArray());
        }
    });

    service = new XxxService();
    Xxx port = service.getXxxPort();

    // invoke webservice and print response
    XxxResponse resp = port.foo();
    System.out.println(resp.toString());

}
```

Comment: Didn't know that java contains this feature. Very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: why it works for me and the `reqContext.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "username");
` approach doesn't is it related to my java version?